# Can see Real-Time Data, but can't see data in a report

Tags: google-analytics, reporting

I can see my real-time event data as I post it.

However, when switching to my dashboard or a report, no data appears.

Do you have to wait a day to see the data in a report that is not real-time?

Thank you in advance,

Karl

Comment: It can take up to 48hrs to see data in analytics, although in my experience I have never had it take more than 4hrs. Also make sure you are selecting todays date in the date range as it doesn't automatically include the current date in the range.

Comment: Thank you, after selecting Today, the data appeared.  Appreciate the assistance, best, Karl

Answer (score 0):

See Confuzing response.

It can take up to 48hrs to see data in analytics, although in my experience I have never had it take more than 4hrs. Also make sure you are selecting todays date in the date range as it doesn't automatically include the current date in the range.